# socket.io without running a node server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a web application that requires PUSH notifications. I looked into node.js and socket.io and have an example that's working. The question I have is, Is it possible to use socket.io only in my client side JS without running a node.js server?

Can a third party server just send requests to a proxy server and may be socket.io just listens to a port on the proxy server and sends back events to it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a server side technology to send data back and forth via web sockets. Socket.io is a communication layer. Which means, you need to have a server side method to send data.

However,

You can use various third party services to use web sockets and notifications. They are relatively easy to use, and they have support for many other languages.

Check some of these out:

- http://pusher.com/
- https://www.firebase.com/
- http://www.pubnub.com/
- https://www.tambur.io/
- https://fanout.io/

You don't need to run Node.js to have a real time push notifications. You can use a third party service that does it for you. Most of them are cheap, sometimes free for low traffic instances.